# Process of reviewing code before creating pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using BitBucket and I would like to know the git commands to pull the work of my colleague to my `localhost`, so that I can review and spot any errors.

I don't want to merge / send this to the live server.

So this is what I tried and the logic behind it:

```
    git checkout development 
    git pull
    git checkout my-colleagues-branch 
    git pull
```

Line 1 & 2 ) **git checkout development** - This is my main live branch and I want to pull the latest merged files into my localhost for testing, so that my localhost is updated with all the latest merges.

Line 3 & 4 ) **git checkout my-colleagues-branch** - This is the branch my colleague created to make changes and is awaiting Pull Request approval. So I am pulling this to my localhost so that I can view his changes.

But this did not pull all of his work in that particular branch. Am I missing something? Or completely doing it wrong?

Comment: This should work if 'my-colleagues-branch' is tracking actual 'my-colleagues-branch' on remote. First 2 lines are not necessary

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the terms, but when you say remote, it means the live server?

Comment: In git, you have remote and local repositories. When you clone a git repository, you'd copy the remote version to your computer. When you create a branch name 'X', that branch, by default tracks the remote branch 'X'. But it's possible that your local branch is not tracking the same remote branch. If you execute 'git branch -vv', you should see 'my-colleagues-branch .    origin/my-colleagues-branch'. If you don't see 'origin' there, delete your local branch and checkout again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the case that your local branch is not tracking the remote branch.
To verify it:

```
git branch -vv
```

you should see 'my-colleagues-branch . origin/my-colleagues-branch'. If you don't see 'origin' there, delete your local branch and checkout again

```
git branch -D my-colleagues-branch
git checkout my-colleagues-branch
```

or simply tell local branch to track the remote one

```
# Assuming you are in my-colleagues-branch and your remote is called origin
git branch -u origin/my-colleagues-branch
```